# Jenkins - Sqlplus plugin: Cannot connect to oracle database. TNSNAMES.ORA missing

Tags: oracle, jenkins, sqlplus

I'm making my way through jenkins but I'm stuck at the moment trying to connect to a remote oracle database in the final step of my job.

Environment vars like ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are ok and sqlplus is running correctly. The connection string seems ok too, I endeed get connected using the same parameters through command line at the same machine, but not inside the job.

Here is the trace:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production

testing directory /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using ORACLE_HOME =/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Running defined script on dweb/********@10.10.20.52:1521/*******
Temp script: /tmp/temp-script-15029865208104609348613017529755.sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORACLE_HOME = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
java.lang.RuntimeException: TNSNAMES.ORA missing!
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplusscriptrunner.SQLPlusRunner.invoke(SQLPlusRunner.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplusscriptrunner.SQLPlusRunner.invoke(SQLPlusRunner.java:16)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sqlplusscriptrunner.SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.perform(SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.java:98)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
ERROR: TNSNAMES.ORA missing!
Finished: FAILURE
```

I even tried setting ORACLE_SID environment var with the same result. Any idea?

For the record: Running jenkins from a docker image

Comment: Sounds like you probably need to [set the TNS_ADMIN to the directory your tnsnames.ora file is in](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TNS_ADMIN).

Comment: But I have none tnsnames.ora file. The database I'm trying to connect against is a remote one, so I have no oracle admin parameters locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SQLPlus+Script+Runner+Plugin

Can it be this plugin (SQLPlusRunner) only supports local naming (TNS)?
In that case, you will have to create a tnsnames.ora file placed in your favorite folder and set `export TNS_ADMIN=/my/favorite/folder`

```
cat tnsnames.ora
MY_TNS_ALIAS=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myip)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SERVICE_NAME)))
```

Now you can configure the connection

```
instance: <MY_TNS_ALIAS>
```

TIP: Make sure you have a succesful connection through sqlplus (CLI) before you continue with jenkins.

For your scenario, I think Oracle Runtime Client would have been a better option to install. Instantclient will work though.

Best of luck!

Bjarte

Comment: I was writting almost the same solution. Thanks!

It seems that the plugin needs a "tnsnames.ora" file to be present at the $ORACLE_HOME path (or $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin) even if you don't need it.

I didn't have to export TNS_ADMIN and my "tnsnames.ora" was an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but this may benefit someone. In my case I did need to add the connection string to tnsnames.ora, but not to export TNS_ADMIN.